# gdb debugger unfamiliar with code displayed

Tags: gdb

I am fairly new to using gdb debugger and so coming across the code being displayed when I ran gdb left me having no use for the debugger. I am unfamiliar with the code being displayed but a did a little research and I assume I accidentally opened up a "thread"? It's hard to explain something I do not understand but I will link a picture explaining what I am talking about. Basically I want to revert back to the "basic" display of my actual code and not this: [displayed by the debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSACw.png)

Comment: You've got a Segmentation Fault and your program died, you can't continue executing it. Now you probably want to fix this Segmentation Fault.

Comment: Please run the `bt` command in gdb and edit your question to include the output.  Your program is calling one of the scanf functions with a NULL stream pointer. You'll need to type `up` a few times to position gdb to look at the code that you wrote; we can help if we can see the backtrace.

Comment: Please don't show *images* of text. Instead, please cut and paste the *actual* text into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your program called one of `scanf` family of functions, with a `NULL` stream.

Usually this happens when you don't check for errors. For example:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("/file/which/does/not/exist", "r");
char ch;

fscanf(fp, "%c", &ch);  /* BUG: should check fp!=NULL first.  */
```

You should *always* check return value from any function that may fail.

You can see which code called into the `fscanf` with GDB `where` command.